# adding selected item data from database to table on selection

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

**Items comes from autosearch:**

[image: Items from autosearch]

**On selecting Iphone the data comes into table:**

[image: Data comes into table]

Please tell me how to do this kind of things in codeigniter using jquery?
It's source is stockpile.techvill.net . You can check the operation in Sales->Add Sales Order ->there you perform this operation.My only problem is of autosearch ,on selection/clicking on items appeared it must be append to table and its calculation. Please provide any example along with its code or where can I refer or search example.

Comment: Although,I was looking for solution on Stackoverflow for solution and I didn't get any answer.So,I asked it last month.I have found the answer by referencing the examples over internet as well as trail and error method on those solutions.I am ready to share my code if asked and if possible Admin may delete my question.

Comment: Right now I am showing the data from database of the same and editing it using Javascript as well as jQuery.My only problem is editing,update and delete the array element of entered data either on update or delete or edit.It same when doing to entered data from CSV file.